# attach common python logging snippet to different class definition?

Tags: python, class, templates, logging

Trying to attach one common snippet into different class for logging/debugging looks like this:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

class ClassDescriptorHelper(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return owner.__name__

class DebugHelper(object):
    def __init__(self, logger_str= "UNDEFINED_DEFAULT", logging_=logging):
        self.logger_ = logging_.getLogger(logger_str)

class LongNameClass():
    #===========================HEAD================================
    name = ClassDescriptorHelper()
    #dbghlp = DebugHelper(logger_str= name )                 # A) not working here, LongNameClass.name also not working 
    dbghlp = DebugHelper(logger_str="LongNameClass")         # A) working, but ugly, have to key in "string" for different class
    dbg = dbghlp.logger_
    #===========================HEAD================================
    def test_debug(self):
        LongNameClass.dbg.info('Sample of Logging info')     ## B) working, but required typing of class name


print LongNameClass.name                                     # A) working 

foo = LongNameClass()
foo.test_debug()
```

The code is working somehow, but ugly:

- A)   Try to get class name with code `"name"` or even `"LongNameClass.name"` not
  working
- B)   for using in class method, the `“LongNameClass.dbg.info”` is
  not easy for typing and read, want something shorter and common...

Anyone can show an improvement sample? Thank you.

Comment: you should be able to use `self.dbg.info(...`. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with your `ClassDescriptorHelper` and  `DebugHelper` classes

Comment: @Trengot  `ClassDescriptorHelper` try to class name in class definition for register `getLogger` automatically with class name somehow , `DebugHelper` try to separate logging module code in class for late use, for example,  use other logging like module.

Comment: and @Trengot, `self.dbg.info` works, any different it from `CLASSNAME.dbg.info`? my understanding is `self` means exists in each instance and `CLASSNAME.dbg.info` means all instances shared, why `self` works?

Comment: Every instance of a class can access the class variables as well. `self.dbg` is the same object as `CLASSNAME.dbg` until you override it (by doing something like `self.dbg = 2`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what's going on with the `ClassDescriptorHelper` and `DebugHelper` classes but assuming that you want to automatically add a logger to every class, I'd look at [annotations/decorators](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/).

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
>>> def add_log(cls):
...     setattr(cls, 'dbg', logging.getLogger(cls.__name__))
...     return cls
... 
>>> @add_log
... class LongClassName:
...     def test_info(self):
...         self.dbg.info("helloWorld")
>>> x = LongClassName()
>>> x.test_info()
INFO:LongClassName:helloWorld
>>>
```

If you try to access an attribute of an instance (such as `self.dbg`), it will first look at its own instance variables, if it doesn't find one it'll look at the class's variable. If it doesn't find it there either it'll keep looking up the inheritance tree (slightly different between old and new style classes).